# Online Chess by VB.net

Tags: vb.net-2010

as the topic header shows my question is about Coding an online chess by VB.net.
I coded the chess game with all rules , now I designed a login form for it, but I don't know how to connect to a Database and send query , to check the User and pass.
I searched about connecting to a DB and I found something. but i didn't found anything about sending query.
I need a code that contains connecting to a DB and sending query for example about checking username and password to DB.
thanks.

Comment: Do you have a concrete question about a programming issue? If not, this is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the simplest answer is to use what's called [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  It's basically a set of classes within the .NET Framework which are used to access a database.  Depending on the database you use, there may be a built-in driver (MS SQL, Access, etc.) or you may need to use a 3rd party one (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.).

[Here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4278/using-adonet-with-sql-server/2/) are a couple of examples.  There are many more.

You can also use [LINQ to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976.aspx), which internally uses ADO.NET but presents the data access to the developer is a more fluent way.  Or take it another step and use [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx).  Etc.

Essentially the question itself is very broad.  There are a number of ways you can access a database.  But these are the places to get started.  If/When you run into specific issues with code not working the way you expect, we'll be happy to help.